# Unwanted Autocomplete suggestions ASP.NET MVC-5 Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Its shows some unwanted `autocomplete` suggestions.
I think those suggestions coming from **`UserName`** text field.
But I do not find any reason for those suggestions.

**Model Code:**

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Birth Date is Reqired")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Display(Name = "Birth Date")]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

**Razor View:**

```
<div class="container jumbotron" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-left: 400px; margin-top:30px">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Registration", "SignUp", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new {@class = "form-control"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new {@class = "form-control"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName)
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new {@class = "form-control"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress, new {@class = "form-control"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BirthDate)
                    <input class="form-control" value="yyyy-MM-dd" name="BirthDate" type="text" id="BirthDate" autocomplete="off">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BirthDate)
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PassWord)
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.PassWord, new {@class = "form-control"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PassWord)
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.VerifyPassWord)
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.VerifyPassWord, new {@class = "form-control"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.VerifyPassWord)
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.VersityId)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VersityId, new {@class = "form-control"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.VersityId)
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PhoneNumber)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, new {@class = "form-control"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PhoneNumber)
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address)
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Address, new {@class = "form-control"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address)
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="ImageUpload" type="file" name="ImageUpload" />
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            }
            <p>
                @Html.ActionLink("Already Have an Account", "LogIn")
            </p>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Problem view** *(Image)* **:**
[Problem indicate by red circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjF6D.png)

I don't want this kinds of suggestions.
Please help me for get ride of this problem.

<sub>*Thanks a lot advance*</sub>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531437/stop-google-chrome-auto-fill-the-input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this site, maybe this is your issue, the autocomplete should do the trick, but if your whole page is rendering over XHTML, then you will need something like this.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/autocomplete-off/

`.autocomplete=”off”` is not valid markup with XHTML Transitional, which is a common DOCTYPE. Use this to keep a vaild markup

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName) {

    var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName(“input”);

    for (i=0; inputElements[i]; i++) {

        if (inputElements[i].className && (inputElements[i].className.indexOf(“disableAutoComplete”) != -1)) {
            inputElements[i].setAttribute(“autocomplete”,”off”);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How I can apply this logic here?

Comment: verify in your partial view if you are using the xhtml mark up in the beginning